# JavaMail Issue with From Attribute

Tags: java, active-directory, jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail to send automated emails from my java code. Following is the code I use to set the 'from' and 'to' attribute.

```
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("XYZ@company.com", "XYZ's alias")); 
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, receiverArray);
```

where `receiverArray` is of type `InternetAddress[]` and contains all the recipients email addresses.

Everything works fine with the functionality and the receiver is receiving the mail but when we open the mail in MS Outlook 2007, the `sender` is shown as `XYZ's alias[XYZ@company.com]` and `to` is shown as the receiver's alias only, may be taken from company's Active Directory on which one can double-click and check the properties.

I need the same to be done for the sender also, i.e. only the alias is shown and not the actual email id.

Maybe some sort of mapping has to be done between the email id I mention in `from` clause and the active directory.

Both the `to` and `from` have registered aliases with the company's Active Directory.

Kindly help. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding the recipient using a string, try an InternetAddress object.  This will give you addresses in RFC 2047 encoding

http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Message.html#addRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType, javax.mail.Address[])

Comment: I have updated the question, actually i am using an array of InternetAddress objects in the 'to' field and it is working absolutely fine. The issue is with the 'from' field. I want the 'from' field to have the same properties as 'to' field i.e. it should not have the email address being displayed but only the alias.